# If $x=8+3\sqrt{7},$ then what is value of $\sqrt{x} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> If $x=8+3\sqrt{7},$ then what is value of $\sqrt{x} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$?

This question is somewhat different than I thought. I only know how to find the value when root is not given . Please help me.

Comment: Use [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question properly.

Comment: What???????????

Comment: I tried to simplify X ×1/X and subtracted 2 from it to make it in form (a+b)^2

Comment: Do you want to calculate $\sqrt{x} \times \frac {1}{\sqrt x}$?

Comment: Yes I want that only

Comment: So answer is $1$.

Comment: Hint: $8 = \sqrt{64}$ and $3\sqrt{7} = \sqrt{63}$.

Comment: I don't see any connection of this question to linear algebra. Please don't abuse the [tag:linear-algebra] tag.

Comment: The value is $\sqrt{8+3\sqrt7}-1/\sqrt{8+3\sqrt7}$.

Comment: @Yves the value is $\sqrt{x+\bar x -2} = \sqrt{ {\rm tr}(x)-2} = \sqrt{16-2}\,$ see my comment on Sharky's answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque: my answer is less error prone. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\left ( \sqrt{x}- \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right )^2 = x + \frac{1}{x} - 2$. Further note that $8+3 \sqrt{7} > 1$, so $\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} > 0$.

$$x=8+3 \sqrt{7} \implies \frac{1}{x} = \frac{8-3\sqrt{7}}{8^2 - (3\sqrt{7})^2} = \frac{8-3\sqrt{7}}{64-63} = 8-3\sqrt{7}.$$

Thus, $x+\frac{1}{x} = 16$, which implies $x + \frac{1}{x} - 2 = 14$. Thus, $\sqrt{x}- \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{14}$.

Comment: You assumed $\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\neq -\sqrt{14}$. To prove it, notice $x>1$, so $$\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} > $$ $$>\sqrt{1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} =0$$

Comment: @user236182 I felt that was trivial to see since $8+3\sqrt{7} > 1$, so $\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. However, you are right in saying that regardless.

Comment: **More clearly:** $\ w\bar w = 1\,\Rightarrow\, (w^{1/2}-w^{-1/2})^2 =\, w+w^{-1}-2 = w+\bar w-2\ \ $

Comment: Another way to see it is $$\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}}>0$$ because $x>1$.